# Facebook app not asking permission for manage_pages

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
 FB.login(function(response){}, {scope: 'user_friends, publish_actions, email, user_location, user_about_me, manage_pages'});

Object {data: Array[4]}data: Array[4]0: Object
permission: "user_friends"status: "granted"
__proto__: Object1: Objectpermission: "email"status: "granted"
__proto__: Object2: Objectpermission: "public_profile"status: "granted"
__proto__: Object3: Objectpermission: "installed"status: "granted"
__proto__: Objectlength: 4__proto__: Array[0]__proto__: Object
```

> above object is for the fb user not even getting page permission popup.

Problem is not decline the page permission request. Its not even ask for page permission to one of my friend account but its getting permission for email (i.e) its asking for email then getting login without asking page permission but pagevamp.com asking page permission for that user

i have checked with some other account its asking permission of manage page.

is it because of any settings in fb ?

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because you need to get the permission *reviewed* by Facebook, before you can ask people that don’t have a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) for it.

When you test this login dialog call yourself with your app admin account, then it should show a clear warning message telling you about this. The message contains links to the documentation that explain the review process further.